# Webserver cannot access external resources, but website is working fine

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, routing

I have a pair of webservers (Windows 2008 R2) configured with NLB.

The website on the server can be accessed *without any issues* by external  as well as internal clients. But the neither of the Webserver can access any external services or urls.

I tried pinging the gateway, but the Request Times out.

NLB is configured in Unicast Mode.

I also tried running only one server (i.e. shutdowg down the other server), but the problem still persists.

I am sure that I have mis-configured the Networking in some way, but I am not sure where to start debugging/solving the issue.

Comment: Have you confirmed that DNS is working on the servers?

Comment: I am trying to connect to the external service by IP address

Answer (score 1):

If you can not access any external resource using its IP address, then most likely you have a very restrictive firewall which allows only specific internal requests and does not allow any originated requests from the web servers.